# Any reason to cast Fortune when able to cast Summon Leprechaun?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-4

In Heroes IV there are two interesting spells. *Fortune* is of level 2, costs 3 mana, and gives a recipient 100% chance to halve any incoming damage. That's powerful -- essentially a universal Ward spell!

*Summon Leprechaun*, at the same time, is a 1st-level spell, costing 2 mana. It summons a stack of 0.33*Level*Meditation Leprechauns. They can cast the same *Fortune* spell at the same turn, and cast it again if you summon more Leprechauns in the stack. After that they may possibly soak a retaliation or two, while your real strikers deal damage.
So, that's available for a weaker Druid, costs less mana, and provideds us with a bonus creature stack.

Is there any reason to cast *Fortune* if *Summon Leprechaun* spell is also available?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no difference, so I guess you should always cast Summon Leprechaun in favor of Fortune. The only thing I learned for sure was that HoMM 4 is terrible compared to either #3 or #5.

Comment: @JackBNimble 1) Why not share that as an answer? 2) Why terrible?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [wiki](http://mightandmagic.wikia.com/wiki/Fortune_(H4)) Summon Leprechaun should be preferred:

> A very useful spell, maximum Luck makes the target creature or hero take 1/3 less damage than they otherwise would. It also cancels the effect of Misfortune. This is a high-priority spell for you melee creatures or heroes in the early game, though casting Summon Leprechaun has essentially the same effect, and you get a bonus creature stack with that spell, so it is a better spell to cast.

However, I can think of these situations:

1. If you have and can afford casting [Mass Fortune](http://mightandmagic.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Fortune) spell it should be obvious choice.
2. If your Leprechauns are crowd controlled (Hypnotize, Berserk, Blind or whatever else) or have already made their turn you should use Fortune instead - Summon spell will simply add creatures to an existing group who won't be able to cast spell this round.